# What do you call a right, but insufficient measure?

Tags: idiom-requests

Imagine, there is a big fire in a house and someone is trying to extinguish it by pouring water from a coffee mug. This person has the right intention (the vector of his deeds points in the right direction -- stopping the fire), but insufficient (the vector length is too short compared to a fire -- too little water).

What do you call a situation like this in English?

In other languages there are following idioms I'm aware of:

- *Drops on a hot stone* in German (*Tropfen auf dem heissen Stein*)
- *Drop in a sea* in Russian (*Капля в море*)

Note that it's different from *fixing a hopelessly broken process* in that the process the person in question is doing is generally right (pouring water to kill a fire), but its **intensity** is insufficient.

Comment: Just like the Russian, 'A drop in the ocean'

Comment: Like feeding an elephant a strawberry?

Comment: spit in the ocean
An inconsequential amount. The image is a single expelled moist mouthful being nothing compared to the entirely watery content of the Atlantic or Pacific. A similar phrase is “a drop in the bucket.” from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/  There are a number of such idioms in English and other languages, all having the base meaning of "An insufficient or inconsequential amount in comparison with what is required."

Comment: There's "Too little, too late".

Comment: See also [English equivalent to “a small fruit in an elephant’s mouth”](//english.stackexchange.com/q/328529/26083) and [“Saving on the parrot’s chocolate is futile”](//english.stackexchange.com/q/62814/26083).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common idiom for this is **drop in the bucket**.

From The Free Dictionary:

> [**drop in the bucket**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+drop+in+the+bucket): a very small or unimportant amount; an insufficient or inconsequential amount in comparison with what is
>   required.

From the OP's question:

> "Imagine, there is a big fire in a house and someone is trying to
>   extinguish it by pouring water from a coffee mug. This person has the
>   right intention (the vector of his deeds points in the right direction
>   -- stopping the fire), but insufficient (the vector length is too short compared to a fire -- too little water)" -- the water from the
>   coffee mug is a **drop in the bucket**.

**Drop in the bucket** bears obvious similarities to:

> - Drops on a hot stone in German (Tropfen auf dem heissen Stein)
> - Drop in a sea in Russian (Капля в море)

Comment: I would be careful, anyone outside of America is unlikely to understand you if you say **a drop in the bucket**.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey are you sure? It's pretty visual.

Answer (score 3):

**A drop in the ocean** would be closest to your original question.

> **Drop in the ocean**  (British, American & Australian) 
>   *also a drop in the bucket (American)*
>   A very small amount in comparison to the amount that is needed
>
> > A hundred thousand may seem a lot but it's a drop in the ocean compared to the millions that need to be spent.

Personally, I have never heard of *a drop in the bucket* - probably since I live in the UK - so if you want to be understood in the UK (or it seems Australia) then **a drop in the ocean** is best.

Comment: A number of non-American dictionaries I've checked indicate *drop in the bucket* is American or North American and *drop in the ocean* is British. Personally, I've never heard anyone in the U.S. say *drop in the ocean*, but if I did, I'm pretty sure I'd understand it. After all, an *ocean* is nothing more than a very large *bucket*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

*pouring water from a coffee mug is a small step in the right direction.*.

> **A step in the right direction.**
>
> an action that increases one's chances of achieving something. 
>   *Exercise won't solve all your health problems, but it's a step in the right direction.* - MW

Also from Wikipedia:.

> A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step"  is a common saying that originated from a famous Chinese proverb [...] ascribed to Laozi.

Comment: For the question, "a *small* step, though a step in the right direction" would convey the idea pretty well.